# implementing Invisible Google reCaptcha for asp.net application ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

This is my ASP.NET form. I want to add invisible recaptcha to it with server side validation. Can someone please help?

I can do client side validation but it doesnt use secret key. My another questions is Do we need secret key for invisible recaptcha?

Please see serverside code that i used for google recaptcha but it is not working for Invisible recaptcha. I am getting this error : - 
**reCAPTCHA Error: missing-input-response: Not Valid Recaptcha**

```
<div id="ContactFormDiv" runat="server">
    <div class="form-row form-required">
        <asp:Label ID="YourNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="YourNameTextBox"> Your Name:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="YourNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form300" MaxLength="150"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row form-required">
            <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
                data-sitekey="site key"
                data-callback="onSubmit"
                data-size="invisible">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row-buttons">
        <asp:Button ID="SendMessageButton" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Send Message" CssClass="buttonPositive"
            CausesValidation="True" OnClick="SendMessageButton_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Serverside Code

```
  public class MyObject
{
    public string success { get; set; }
}

public static string ReCaptcha_Key = "------------------Site Key-----------------";
public static string ReCaptcha_Secret = "--------------Secret Key ---------------";

 public bool ValidateReCaptcha()
{
    bool Valid = false;
    //start building recaptch api call
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    //Getting Response String Append to Post Method
    string Response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];

    string url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + ReCaptcha_Secret + "&response=" + Response;
    sb.Append(url);

    //make the api call and determine validity
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var uri = sb.ToString();
        var json = client.DownloadString(uri);
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RecaptchaApiResponse));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        var result = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as RecaptchaApiResponse;

        //--- Check if we are able to call api or not.
        if (result == null)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Captcha was unable to make the api call";
        }
        else // If Yes
        {
            //api call contains errors
            if (result.ErrorCodes != null)
            {
                if (result.ErrorCodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.ErrorCodes)
                    {
                        lblmsg.Text = "reCAPTCHA Error: " + error;
                    }
                }
            }
            else //api does not contain errors
            {
                if (!result.Success) //captcha was unsuccessful for some reason
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Captcha did not pass, please try again.";
                }
                else //---- If successfully verified. Do your rest of logic.
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Captcha cleared ";
                    Valid = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Valid;
}

public bool temp = true;
protected void SendMessageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    temp = ValidateReCaptcha();
    if (temp == false)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Not Valid Recaptcha";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Successful";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }

    Page.Validate();

    if (this.Page.IsValid == true && temp == true)
    { //Page and invisible recaptcha is valid  }
 }
```

I am getting this error : - 
**reCAPTCHA Error: missing-input-response: Not Valid Recaptcha**

Comment: Invisible recaptcha? That does not make sense. Doesn't that defy the purpose of using it?

Comment: @VDWWD Please search Google Invisible reCaptcha https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

Comment: ok... It does exists. Sorry about that. The only difference is that you do not have to click the checkbox, but the rest seems the same and if it still not trusts you it will still show the validation.

Comment: Be careful using `Response` as a variable name as there is also a Response object. Also check you are getting a value from `Request["g-recaptcha-response"]`

Comment: Jon P i am not getting value from Request["g-recaptcha-response"]

Answer (score 8):

This is how I implemented the working sample:

-- Client Side (Refer to [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) )

```html
<head>
 <!-- Google Invisible Captcha -->
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'/>
 <script>
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("htmlForm").submit();
        }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="htmlForm" action="Default.aspx" method="post">
  <input name="txtName"  />
  <input name="txtEmailAddress"  />
  <button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-default"
                    data-sitekey="-------------------Site key--------------"
                    data-callback="onSubmit">
                    Submit Request
  </button>
 </form>
</body>
```

-- Server Side (keeps secret Key)

```
    public static bool IsValidCaptcha()
    {

        var secret = "--------------Secret Key ---------------";
        var req =
            (HttpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secret + "&response=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"]);

        using (var wResponse = req.GetResponse())
        {

            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseFromServer = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                if (!responseFromServer.Contains("\"success\": false"))
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Barsham , I will try to run this.

Comment: I tried to use this code, but it is wrong the part where it says " + secret + " should be after the actual parameter  secret, otherwise people will get always a 404 error.

Comment: Can we declare the function like this " public static bool IsValidCaptcha(string secret) " to use it for multiple forms with different Secret Keys ?

Comment: Yes should be fine.

Comment: That's pretty useless since it only verifies the key and does nothing with the score.

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar problem and it looks like it is harder to find any decent example. However, I saw that you have set 
    data-callback="onSubmit"
but I didn't see where you have defined that method. Is it there? Could that be what are you missing?